# How to display a tutorial / information on users first login?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a social network site, and I am wondering how can I display a interactive tutorial and information on users first login.
Such as only on the first login, users are asked to fill more information on their profile .
How can I achieve this though php and mysql?
Example:
[image]

Comment: it will be better if you can more details, have you developed your own authentication system ? or are you using tankAuth, etc ? do you track registration datetime and last login time ?

Comment: Are you using an opensource option? Or is it your own codes (if it were i doubt you would ask here as its pretty simple). If you are using opensource/other plugins please provide links. @Wesley answer is good enough otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

When a user signs up to your website, you can add a field which stores the date of their last login. When that field is still `NULL` for example - it's their first login.

Comment: That way, only the first visited page will display the tutorial / intro page, unless you keep the state in a session or cookie. You might want to display it until the user either confirms or dismisses the page.

Comment: Correct, it depends on how you want this to work. I could understand that if someone browses away he/she doesn't want the tutorial to popup every time until she hits some cross. But it depends on the application requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by simply adding a column to your `userprefs` table (or whatever you use to store your user-specific settings), with a boolean/int defining whether they've completed the tutorial.

Upon completion (or when the user clicks Dismiss), you set the value for that user to true/1.

Comment: But then you'll have to make a query to DB in order to get the boolean value and check it everytime user signs in